# Windows do not fully extend to the top when dragged accross monitors for the first time

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1803

[image]

Under Windows 10 build 17134 (Public April 2018 update), when dragging windows accross screens, they will not extend all the way to the top and show a white bar on applications that use custom drawn titlebars when they change screens on an asymmetrical 3-monitor setup (Pictured above). When they show this behavior, dragging them to the top once more gets them to fully extend. This applies to the maximize button too and I've seen forum posts about this on Google that lead to no subsequent leads.

I am using an Nvidia graphics card, but I see no reason as to why that would cause this behavior. This system is a clean install from the Falls Creator Update, maybe something residual during the update process is left broken on some systems?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using an insider preview build means that you accept having funny problems.
The software you are using has not been fully tested, and you have just
volunteered to become such a tester.

The proper action is to report the problem to Microsoft and wait for the
final release.

Just a note that sometimes the only way to install the final release over the
insider preview version is a full install. Unless you are a software
developer, ready to wipe out your installation and start anew in the interest
of testing your own application, insider preview builds are problematic
and best installed in temporary virtual machines.

Comment: I am opted out of the Windows Insider Program. Build 17134 is the latest public build, AKA the April update or Redstone 4. It's currently being distributed in the slow ring.

Comment: Build 17134 is the final candidate for version 1803, so why not install the stable version 1803? Not many people on this site have experience with build 17134 and it's unlikely we would be motivated to fix problems with it that may have already been fixed with version 1803.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Why would my build be an Insider build if it's currently being distributed widely to everyone trough the default, basic Windows settings? Again, I have not willingly installed any sort of special version. I installed this device using the consumer installer from Microsoft themselves and I just went to check again - _The Windows Insider option is not even set up._ I am not getting any sort of special treatment trough Windows Update, I'm getting the version of Windows that everybody else is getting at the moment (1803) with build 17134.48.

Comment: Just as clarification, Windows Update is currently set to "Semi-Annual Channel". Also, I don't want you to get the wrong idea - I'm trusting what you say, it's just almost unbelievable to me that this would happen despite all my settings requesting that not to be the case. In case this changes anything, I live in Belgium, and my laptop running Windows 10 Pro without a Microsoft account and with the same, default settings, has the same build.

Comment: It's also incredible for me that you got this update at all, unless you're really an Insider with all the risks involved.